# How to block website from reading my IP?

Tags: video, watch

I want to watch videos on a website but I can only access my country's version. Whenever I type in say `.ca` (Canada) instead of `.il` (Israel), I get redirected to `.il`.

How can I surpass that?

Comment: What's CA and IL?

Comment: .ca: Canada
.il: Israel

Answer (score 5):

Somehow something has to know your ip address, or else the server would be unable to make a connection back to you. A proxy would sit in between you and the host such that you would connect to the proxy and the proxy would connect to the server. Ideally you could get a proxy in the country you want to appear to be connected from.

A quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=web+surf+proxy).

Comment: That search might need the word "anonymizing" then -- http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=anonymizing+proxy+server

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way the internet works, a website always needs to know 'your' IP address, so you can't really block a website from seeing it. BUT, you could use a proxy server which would essentially hide your IP address from websites and, depending on the location of the proxy, you could fool websites that you are coming from America

One possible solution is to use an anonymous proxy, such as TOR, an SSH tunnel, or a PHProxy.

The quickest solution would have to a PHProxy. You can find plenty using a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&q=phproxy+%2B%22Includes+a+mini+URL-form+on+every+HTML+page%22+%2Bintitle%3A%22PHProxy%22+%2B%22Store+cookies+for+this+session+only%22&aq=f&oq=&aqi=). Here's an [example PHProxy site](http://profile.iiita.ac.in/sranjan1_01/shaktie/).

A possibly more 'secure' and anonymous proxy is TOR. Here is what [their website](http://www.torproject.org/) has to say about themselves:

> Tor protects you by bouncing your communications around a distributed network of relays run by volunteers all around the world

Checkout this [Lifehacker snippit](http://lifehacker.com/331996/browse-the-internet-anonymously-with-tor) for instructions on setting it up

Comment: -100 for not reading the question properly.
-1000 for suggesting watching video over tor, noobish usage like that will kill the tor network one day.

Comment: How did I not read the question properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at using Hotspot Shield 
its rather handy for both accessing video not always available to your area as well as security on random access points.

below is cut and paste from www.hotspotshield.com

```
*  Secure your web session with HTTPS encryption.
* Hide your IP address for your privacy online.
* Access all content privately without censorship; bypass firewalls.
* Protect yourself from snoopers at Wi-Fi hotspots, hotels, airports, corporate offices and ISP hubs.
* Works on wireless and wired connections alike.
* Secure your data & personal information online.
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation: [Panix](http://www.panix.com) offers a proxy to all their customers.  For $100 (US) per year you get unlimited use.  It would resolve to the USA.

Answer (score 0):

The only way around showing your IP address is using a proxy server such as zend2.com

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is suggesting using a proxy server, which is really the only way to go, you have to make sure you use a *fast* one, and one from the county the site you are visiting is filtering for.  Here is pretty decent tutorial that walks one through setting up Tor to talk to the BBC (in the UK), but the instructions would apply to any similar situation:

http://hurwi.net/blog/?p=28

If you use the site they reccommend in that article (the .eu one) I would recommend accessing it via a throwaway VM, as my browser seems to flag it as an "untrusted" site.  Also, you may want to filter the list by "fast" as well as "exit" to ensure you get a faster connection.